# Can an Elk make an attack of opportunity with its Hooves when an adjacent creature stands up from being prone?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, reach, prone

The rulebook says that an attack of opportunity can be done on a foe leaving your *reach* area without disengaging. My thought is kind of reminiscent of the old wording "leaving a **threatened** area", but anyways, here it is :

The "hooves" attack action description is as follows :

> **Hooves:** Melee Weapon Attack: +5 to hit, ***reach 5 ft. one prone creature.*** Hit: 8 (2d4 + 3) bludgeoning damage.

(emphasis added; quote slightly modified for clarity)

Technically, could the hooves attack range be considered 5ft-ground, causing a standing-up character withing 5ft of an Elk's hooves to trigger an attack of opportunity?

---

Note: This question is not a duplicate. It is specific to the Hooves attack which has very limited usage. The target needs to be proned and within 5 feet. This question is not about "how to perform an attack of opportunity", but rather IF one can be performed with a hooves attack under certain conditions.

Comment: Related: "[Does standing up from prone trigger the damage from Booming Blade?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73552)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

The reach is 5ft and can only hit 1 prone creature. The reach is not "5ft on the ground only." For example, you could target a prone creature laying on top of a low table. They do not need to be on the ground - just prone within 5 feet.

The mechanic of standing up from prone requires you to use your movement feet, but does not actually entail you moving anywhere. The feet used to stand is representative of the time you need to recover, not the distance traveled. A human does not move 15 feet when they stand up. Standing up does not trigger opportunity attacks.

Even by the old wording you are not leaving a threatened AREA, you are leaving a "condition"(at best) that could be exploited by hooves.

The argument could be made an attack of opportunity is possible while a prone creature is crawling away without standing up.

Comment: A clearer way to phrase the point in your first paragraph might be that the **reach** of the attack is simply 5 feet, whereas "one prone creature" is a **targeting restriction**. As you say, standing up just means they no longer meet the necessary condition to be targeted by the Hooves attack, not that they're leaving the attack's reach.

Answer (score 10):

### Opportunity attacks happen when the opponent leaves your reach

Standing up doesn’t do this. Nor does running around you in circles within 5-feet. The target must move from within 5-feet of you to *not* within 5-feet of you.

If they are prone while they do that (i.e. they crawl) you can use Hooves.

Comment: The question is specifically asking if the standing from a prone position (leaving the "range" of the attack as he sees it) triggers an attack of opportunity.

Answer (score 2):

### You do not move when you stand from prone and thus standing from prone cannot provoke an opportunity attack

The rules on "[Opportunity Attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#OpportunityAttacks)" state the following:

> [...] You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you can see **moves out of your reach** [...]

There already exists a similar question here:

- "[Does standing up from prone trigger the damage from Booming Blade?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73552)"

The answers there establish that *booming blade* triggers its damage when the target moves and that the damage *does not trigger* when a creature stands up. Thus, **standing up does not count as moving and cannot provoke an opportunity attack.**

The answers there are well-accepted but [the following unofficial ruling (a tweet)](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/663030224154562561) from lead game designer Jeremy Crawford used in BloodCinder's answer also exists:

> **Question:** For Booming Blade, did you intend for standing up from prone to trigger the extra damage? It costs movement.
>
> **Crawford's Answer:** Standing up costs movement but moves you nowhere. To move while prone, you crawl or use magic (PH, 191).

Note that Crawford's quote is *somewhat* problematic because [teleporting *also* does not count as moving](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122943)...

For a more direct answer there also already exists the following question:

- "[Does standing up from being prone provoke an attack of opportunity?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55139)"

Comment: You _do_ move when standing up from prone, in both the conventional sense (your location in space changes) and the game-mechanics sense (you spend movement). You just don't move out of reach.

Comment: @MarkWells No you don't. See the linked question, *booming blade* activates when you move and it does not activate when you stand up. Thus, standing up does not count as moving. "Standing up costs movement but moves you nowhere."

Comment: You can't generalize rulings into rules. What makes them rulings is that they're situational. A pattern of rulings may suggest an interpretation of the rules, but a single point doesn't. _Booming blade_ is an outlier in many ways and drawing any larger conclusions from it is a mistake.

Comment: @MarkWells Neither answer there specifically concerns itself with *booming blade*, nor is the cantrip in any way exceptional. It has a clear trigger, "movement", and that is not triggered when standing from prone. Thus *anything* that requires movement cannot trigger when standing from prone or else those answers are incorrect. There is no "larger conclusion" when the only is question is "does standing from prone count as "movement"?" If you'd like, I can open this as its own question

Comment: The larger conclusion you're drawing is that standing from prone doesn't count as movement, based on the evidence that standing from prone doesn't trigger _booming blade_ (if you happen to be at Jeremy Crawford's table, which I'll point out that most of us aren't). There is no reason for the question "Does X count as Y?" to have a consistent, universally applicable answer. That's why the _booming blade_ thing is a _ruling_.

Comment: @MarkWells Why is there no reason for it to have a consistent answer? It's a question of whether X belongs to group Y, that is yes or no question. Also Crawford is not the only answer I am talking about. The first answer to the booming blade question does not mention him at all and is still well-accepted